# Why isn't PDDL compiling correctly and resulting in parse error?

Tags: planning, pddl

I am new to `PDDL` so I don't understand very well what's going on but I have this issue and it seems that black-box planner isn't able to parse my `PDDL` code.

Here there is the **domain**:

```
(define (domain vacuum)
    (:requirements :strips)
    (:predicates
        (clean ?x)
        (in_room ?x ?r)
        (door_to ?r1 ?r2)
        (dirty ?x)
    )

    (:action moveToAction
        :parameters (?ob ?r1 ?r2)
        :precondition (and
            (in_room ?ob ?r1)
            (door_to ?r1 ?r2)
        )
        :effect (and
            (not (in_room ?r1))
            (in_room ?ob ?r2)
        )
    )
    
    (:action cleanAction
        :parameters (?r1)
        :precondition (and
            (dirty ?r1)
        )
        :effect (and
            (clean ?r1)
        )
    )
)
```

and here there is the **problem**:

```
(define (problem vacuum)
    (:domain vacuum)
    (:objects vacuum kitchen corridor bedroom1 bedroom2 bathroom living_room)
    (:init  
        (dirty kitchen) 
        (dirty bedroom1) 
        (dirty bedroom2)
        (dirty living_room) 
        (dirty bathroom) 
        (dirty corridor)
        (in_room vacuum living_room)
        (not in_room vacuum kitchen) 
        (not in_room vacuum bedroom1) 
        (not in_room vacuum bedroom2) 
        (not in_room vacuum bathroom) 
        (not in_room vacuum corridor) 
        (door_to bathroom corridor) 
        (door_to kitchen corridor) 
        (door_to living_room corridor) 
        (door_to bedroom1 corridor) 
        (door_to bedroom2 corridor) 
        (door_to corridor bathroom) 
        (door_to corridor kitchen)
        (door_to corridor living_room)
        (door_to corridor bedroom1)
        (door_to corridor bedroom2)
    )
    (:goal 
        (and (clean living_room))
    )
)
```

The exact error that the solver gives me is:

```
parse error
Error occurred at or near line 40
```

If I understood correctly the parser reads the domain file first and the problem file after that, so the error should be in the problem file, and in particular in the `init`. The precise line should be `(dirty corridor)`.
I do not understand what I did wrong, did I miss the syntax completely or did I just mess something?

Comment: +1 for @Bilal's answer - the negative intializations should be removed from the `:init`, but if you need to negate a predicate, the syntax you used in the `move` action effect was correct:

`(not (in_room ?r1))`

This is NOT how negation is written:

`(not in_room vacuum kitchen)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove the **negated predicates** from the initial state in the problem due to the [Closed World Assumption](https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/requirements#open-world), plus you have a small typo in the domain `in_room` takes two variables, and not just one!

Then your domain / problem will look like:

#### Domain:

```
(define (domain vacuum)
    (:requirements :strips)
    (:predicates
        (clean ?x)
        (in_room ?x ?r)
        (door_to ?r1 ?r2)
        (dirty ?x)
    )

    (:action moveToAction
        :parameters (?ob ?r1 ?r2)
        :precondition (and
            (in_room ?ob ?r1)
            (door_to ?r1 ?r2)
        )
        :effect (and
            (not (in_room ?ob ?r1))
            (in_room ?ob ?r2)
        )
    )
    
    (:action cleanAction
        :parameters (?r1)
        :precondition (and
            (dirty ?r1)
        )
        :effect (and
            (clean ?r1)
        )
    )
)
```

#### Problem

```
(define (problem vacuum)
    (:domain vacuum)
    (:objects vacuum kitchen corridor bedroom1 bedroom2 bathroom living_room)
    (:init  
        (dirty kitchen) 
        (dirty bedroom1) 
        (dirty bedroom2)
        (dirty living_room) 
        (dirty bathroom) 
        (dirty corridor)
        (in_room vacuum living_room)
        (door_to bathroom corridor) 
        (door_to kitchen corridor) 
        (door_to living_room corridor) 
        (door_to bedroom1 corridor) 
        (door_to bedroom2 corridor) 
        (door_to corridor bathroom) 
        (door_to corridor kitchen)
        (door_to corridor living_room)
        (door_to corridor bedroom1)
        (door_to corridor bedroom2)
    )
    (:goal 
        (and (clean living_room))
    )
)
```

### Output Plan:

```
  (:action cleanaction
    :parameters (living_room)
    :precondition
      (and
        (dirty living_room)
      )
    :effect
      (and
        (clean living_room)
      )
  )
```

Comment: While it is true that most planners assume a Closed World, PDDL still accepts negative literals in the initial state. The PDDL BNF states that `<init-el> ::= <literal(name)>` and `<literal(t)> ::= <atomic formula(t)>` and `<literal(t)> ::= (not <atomic formula(t)>)`. So it is perfectly valid without requirements. If the OP used the correct syntax `(not (in_room vacuum kitchen))` it would be valid. Whether the black-box planner likes it is another story, but it is perfectly valid PDDL. While CW makes it  redundant, it is sometimes used for readability or due to automatic state generation.